# how to C++ call Objective-C method?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm using AudioQueue to analyze the audio frequency. I saw the SpeakHere example by Apple.

I know to use the callback function to get the audio data in inbuffer->mAudioData. The question is when I get the audio data, I want to update the spectrum on the UI. The UI is code use Objective-C and the SpeakHere code use C++. I don't know how to call the UI method in the callback function and pass the mAudioData.

**Here is the callback function:**

```
// AudioQueue callback function, called when an input buffers has been filled.

void AQRecorder::MyInputBufferHandler(  void *                              inUserData,     
                                    AudioQueueRef                       inAQ,
                                    AudioQueueBufferRef                 inBuffer,   
                                    const AudioTimeStamp *              inStartTime,
                                    UInt32                              inNumPackets,
                                    const AudioStreamPacketDescription* inPacketDesc)
{
   AQRecorder *aqr = (AQRecorder *)inUserData;
   aqr->currentQueueBufferRef = inBuffer;

   try {
       if (inNumPackets > 0) {
           // write packets to file
            XThrowIfError(AudioFileWritePackets(aqr->mRecordFile, FALSE, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                         inPacketDesc, aqr->mRecordPacket, &inNumPackets, inBuffer->mAudioData),
                   "AudioFileWritePackets failed");

        ***//Here I want to call Objective c Method and pass the value.***

    }

    // if we're not stopping, re-enqueue the buffe so that it gets filled again
    if (aqr->IsRunning())
        XThrowIfError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
   } catch (CAXException e) {
    char buf[256];
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n", e.mOperation, e.FormatError(buf));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use both `C++` and `Objective-C` in the same file, please make sure the extension of the file is `.mm` instead of `.m` or `.cpp`. This way, the compiler knows it's `Objective-C++`, and it compiles without a problem.

Somebody has explained it in detail in this blog post: [Mixing Objective-C, C++ and Objective-C++](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++)

Comment: Hi Vikram Singh ! Thank you very much so fast to replay. Yes, the extension of the file is .mm. The c++ callback function is static method, I was not familiar with c++. I mean is that if I can define a protocol in c++ file(the extension of the file is also .mm) ? And in the UI class we can implementation the method.

Comment: I am not very clear with your requirements but yes, you can implement your callback C++ method in your UI objective-c class and then call the objective-c code to update the UI from within your callback C++ function.